# Chrome Extension - send post request at certain time using external server

Tags: google-chrome, post, google-chrome-extension, http-post, fetch-api

I am currently building a Chrome extension that lets users auto-register for courses on a particular website once registration opens. The registration process is just a simple fetch POST request with an authentication header.

Now, this already works using the chrome.alarms API while the browser is open, but for obvious reasons I would want this to also work once the user closes the browser. Do you have any ideas how to do this? I really want to avoid to externally save user data..

If this is impossible, my idea would be to send the registration fetch to an external server (maybe even one hosted on a Raspberry Pi? Other ideas?) and then execute it once the registration opens.

Comment: "but for obvious reasons I would want this to also work once the user closes the browser" --- Do you also want it work work when the user shuts down their computer? Because then the external server is the only solution.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I am currently working on a node.js/express solution hosted on a Raspberry Pi. But I am not a huge fan, since the authorization keys and user info will be stored on it. I don't even know if it's publishable on the Chrome Web Store this way..